# How-to avoid IndexOutOfBounds Exception when Dynamically Updating JComboBox (Debugging help)

Tags: java, swing

I wrote a GUI using SWING API.

I got a set of forms, each form assists the user to create a pre-defined type of object. Upon completion, the user confirms creation by a click of a *JButton*.

I got a class (**DataManager**) that follows a singleton pattern. Additionally, the class follows an observer and factory patterns. The **DataManager** is an observable object. The data which is observed is in following format:

```
public static List<Target> targets = new ArrayList<Target>();
```

**DataManager** class holds a set of methods to create a pre-define type of an object.
Example:

```
public static final void createTarget(String id, double x, double y, double z){
    targets.add(new Target(id,x,y,z));
    notifyTargetObservers();
}
```

One of the forms is an observer object which observes DataManager for updates in any of the data held in its lists (Ex. list targets...).

**IObserve**:

```
public interface IObserve {
public void updateTargets();
public void updateSources();
public void updateFluids();
}
```

The observer implements the methods introduced in **IObserver**.
Example:

```
@Override   
public void updateTargets(){  
cbAnalysisTargets.addItem(DataManager.targets.get(DataManager.targets.size()-1));
    }
```

The *cbAnalysisTargets* is a **JComboBox** which requires to be updated dynamically as new objects are introduced into the environment.
**IObservable**:

```
public abstract class IObservable {
private static Set<IObserve> targetObservers = new HashSet<IObserve>();
private static Set<IObserve> sourceObservers = new HashSet<IObserve>();
private static Set<IObserve> fluidObservers = new HashSet<IObserve>();

public final void addTargetObserver(IObserve o){
    targetObservers.add(o);
}

public final void addSourceObserver(IObserve o){
    sourceObservers.add(o);
}

public final void addFluidObserver(IObserve o){
    fluidObservers.add(o);
}


public static final void notifyTargetObservers(){
    for(IObserve observer : targetObservers){
        observer.updateTargets();
    }
}

public static final void notifySourceObservers(){
    for(IObserve observer : sourceObservers){
        observer.updateSources();
    }
}

public static final void notifyFluidObservers(){
    for(IObserve observer : fluidObservers){
        observer.updateFluids();
    }
  }
}
```

The issue lays in **IndexOutOfBounds** Exception. The exception crops up in a following scenario:
 1. The user opens first form and successfuly initiates creation of 2 pre-defined objects of the same type.
 2. The user opens second form; fills out the form and upon confirmation (click of a button) receives an exception stated bellow.

Ideally, I would like to be assisted in addressing following issue and resolving the exception stated bellow.

Exception:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
>       at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
>       at fprof.application.data.frame.manager.content.AnalysisCreatorPanel.updateSources(AnalysisCreatorPanel.java:99)
>       at fprof.application.utility.IObservable.notifySourceObservers(IObservable.java:32)
>       at fprof.application.data.manager.IDataManager.createSource(IDataManager.java:29)
>       at fprof.application.data.frame.manager.content.SourceCreatorPanel$1.actionPerformed(SourceCreatorPanel.java:127)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

**EDIT 1:** 
updateSource Method:

```
@Override
    public void updateSources(){
        cbAnalysisSources.addItem(DataManager.sources.get(DataManager.sources.size()-1));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some introduction to basic debugging in Eclipse, because this is super important and would solve almost all of your errors and bugs. There is a lot Eclipse can help you with, but I'll show you just the basics and you can read and explore from there. It will be useful nonetheless.

I made a simple piece of code to work on:

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] array = new int[] {12, 14, 523, 5423, 12, 0 ,14, -3, 521, 2};
        int pos = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            array[i] = -1;
            pos = increment(pos);
        }
    }

    static int increment(int pos) {

        int num = pos + 1;
        return num;
    }
}
```

If you run it, it will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. To debug, we will need to set a breakpoint somewhere in the code where we think the problem starts at, possibly close to the line that thrown the exception. **The idea behind a breakpoint, is that the code will stop running when it reaches the line which was marked with a breakpoint**. Breakpoints are entered by doubleclicking on the left bar in the editor next to the appropriate line (see red circle). You can enter several breakpoints at different places. Then, click on the `Debug` button (yellow circle). Make sure it's not the `Run` button, because that will ignore breakpoints.

[image]

You will then be taken to the Debug perspective, which offers different views (my views are rearranged from the default):

[image]

What you see here are:

1. View listing all the variables (including fields, arrays etc.) and their value. For objects (class instances and arrays), you will have an expand arrow to show their class members and properties. Whenever there is a c change in one of those values, it will be highlighted in yellow.
2. Displays the values of the selected line the view above. Some objects are long and complicated, so it's handy to see it there.
3. The normal editor, but with a highlighter that shows you where the code is at. Soon we will talk about that. Here the code is at the breakpoint, because this is where it will stop for the first time.
4. Just the console to see prints.
5. Information about threads. When you run multi-thread programs, it will list all the threads and their state. Here you will see that the thread `main` is `suspended` with the reason `breakpoint at line 9`, which is what it's supposed to be.

Now onto the "debugging itself". You will find many option under the `Run` menu, but the useful ones are:

- `F6 - step over`: this will advance to the next line in the code **while skipping method calls**.
- `F5 - step into`: this will advance to the next line in the code and **will enter method calls**. Note that if you have the JDK (or the JRE with source attached), it *will* step into Oracle's libraries, which is usually not something you want. Sometimes their code is very complicated and if you continue stepping into it you might never come back...
- `F8 - resume`: this will run the code until the next breakpoint is reached. It can be the same breakpoint in the editor if you are running in a loop, for example.
- `F7 - step return`: this will run the code until the current method returns (if applicable).
- `Ctrl-R - run to line`: this will run the code until the line where you placed the caret at.

Demonstration:

1. Press `F5` of `F6`, you will see that in view 1, the variable `i` was added since it was creating in the while loop. Its value is 0 as assigned.
2. Press `F5` of `F6`, you will see a yellow highlight on the `[0]` of `array` with its new value `-1` as assigned in the code (you have to have the array variable expanded).
3. Press `F6` (will do `F5` next iteration), now `pos` is highlighted since the method assigned a new value to it. The debugger will run back to the loop.
4. Repeat steps 1 and 2, `i` and `array[1]` will change.
5. Press `F5`, you will be taken into `increment`. Note that the only the **local variable** `pos` is shown since all other variables are out of scope.
6. Press `F5` of `F6` until you reach the loop (line 9) again. You will be taken out of the method. Observe how `pos` changed.
7. Press `F8`, the code will run a full iteration and stop at the breakpoint again. Note the values changed.
8. Put your caret at line 17 and press `Ctrl+R`. The code will run until line 17 as if stepping over everything until it is reached.
9. Press `F7`, the code will run until `increment` returns. `pos` will not be updated until the next step, but `i` is highlighted since it's the first time you have an opportunity to see the change made in the `for` loop (line 9).
10. Continue running the code with `F8`, eventually you will notice that it stops at line 10. This is because an exception will be thrown at this line if you advance any further. It is an automatic breakpoint to alert you about the exception.
11. Press `F6` once, if you have code attached you will be taken to Oracle's code in class `Thread` method `dispatchUncaughtException`.
12. Press `F6` again, the exception will be thrown and the program will terminate. This is the stage you would be at if you just ran the code normally. Now, however, you will be able to see exactly which variables changed when and how, so understanding why the exception is thrown and where the problem is is much easier.

Try running the debugger in more complicated situations until you feel comfortable with it. You can change `pos` to `i` to make the program a bit more interesting. This is

> How-to avoid IndexOutOfBounds Exception.

If you have any questions leave a comment.