# Code Iterates 13 times then stops

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

Iteration works for 14 runs but then decides to get stuck in a loop and not produce anymore values. Not sure why, looks fine to me. I've checked the while loops and they make sense to me when I write it out as well. Not sure if the thirteenth or fourteenth iteration is important for why it stops. I also cant tell if it is just my computer taking awhile to compile all this data. This is only part of the code I am working on for a project. Please help!

```
for (int c = 0; c < 50; c++) {
    //for loop here(for the 1000 times it occurs
    //create a temp array for gene expression and the subfamily
    String[] tempArray1 = OlfrOP6; //array used to select genes from
    String[] tempArray2 = subOP6; //corresponding array to get subfamily
    Random randomizer = new Random();
    int random = 0;

    String[] fictCellOlfr = new String[OP6counter];
    String[] fictCellSub = new String[OP6counter];
    for (int a = 0; a < OP6counter; a++) {
        boolean neg = true;
        int count = 0;
        random = randomizer.nextInt(1113);
        while (neg == true) {
            if (tempArray1[random].equals("-1")) {
                random = randomizer.nextInt(1113);
            } else {
                fictCellOlfr[a] = tempArray1[random];
                fictCellSub[a] = tempArray2[random];
                tempArray1[random] = "-1";
                neg = false;
            }
        }

    }
    tempArray1 = OlfrOP6;
    tempArray2 = subOP6;

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fictCellOlfr));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fictCellSub));


    ArrayList < String > freqTempSub = new ArrayList < String > ();
    ArrayList < Integer > freqTempSubCounter = new ArrayList < Integer > ();

    freqTempSub.add(0, fictCellSub[0]);
    freqTempSubCounter.add(0, 1);
    for (int i = 1; i < 79; i++) {
        String temp = fictCellSub[i];
        boolean button = true;
        for (int h = 0; h < freqTempSub.size(); h++) {
            if (freqTempSub.get(h).equals(temp)) {
                int temp2 = freqTempSubCounter.get(h);
                freqTempSubCounter.set(h, temp2 + 1);
                button = false;
            }

        }
        if (button == true) {
            freqTempSub.add(temp);
            freqTempSubCounter.add(1);
        }

    }



    //add this to excel
    //Need to change this code so that it extends two columnns not chop it up           
    int d = 3 * (c + 1);
    for (int a = 1; a <= freqTempSub.size(); a++) {
        Cell name = outputSheet.getRow(0).createCell(d);
        name.setCellValue("Subfamily");
        Cell name1 = outputSheet.getRow(0).createCell(d + 1);
        name1.setCellValue("Frequency");
        String x = freqTempSub.get(a - 1);
        String y = Integer.toString(freqTempSubCounter.get(a - 1));
        String z = Integer.toString(freqTempSubCounter.size());
        Cell cell = outputSheet.getRow(a).createCell(d); //null because freqTemp may be bigger than original
        cell.setCellValue(x);
        Cell cell1 = outputSheet.getRow(a).createCell(d + 1);
        cell1.setCellValue(y + "/" + z);
    }
    uniqueSub.add(freqTempSubCounter.size());
    //now add uniqueSub to Sheet 2 so that it can be used to make graph
    System.out.println(uniqueSub);
}
for (int i = 1; i <= uniqueSub.size(); i++) {
    Cell name = outputSheet1.createRow(0).createCell(0);
    Cell cell = outputSheet1.createRow(i).createCell(0);
    name.setCellValue("Unique Subfamily");
    cell.setCellValue(uniqueSub.get(i - 1));
}
```

Comment: Does your IDE come with a debugger?

Comment: I do not believe so, how do I check? I'm using eclipse of that helps...

Comment: Yup, eclipse comes with a debugger. Here's a tutorial on using it: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

I found that after a quick Google search, I'm not sure how helpful it is, but I'm positive there are more out there.

Comment: You might want to post more of your code.

Comment: `Not sure why, looks fine to me` Seems like you should be using the built in debugger to learn why heh

Comment: You are using `Cell` but you did not define it. In any case, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996744/how-to-avoid-indexoutofbounds-exception-when-dynamically-updating-jcombobox/30009388#30009388) is an answer I gave someone which explains how to use the Eclipse debugger. I think it will help you a lot.